# trouble with AWS SWF using IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, flash, credentials, amazon-iam

I've noticed on AWS that if I get IAM role credentials (key, secret, token) and set them as appropriate environment variables in a python script, I am able to create and use SWF Layer1 objects just fine. However, it looks like the Layer2 objects do not work. For example, if I have boto and os imported, and do:

```
test = boto.swf.layer2.ActivityWorker()
test.domain = 'someDomain'
test.task_list = 'someTaskList'
test.poll()
```

I get an exception that the security token is not valid, and indeed, if I dig through the object, the security token is not set. This even happens with:

```
test = boto.swf.layer2.ActivityWorker(session_token=os.environ.get('AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN'))
```

I can fix this by doing:

```
test._swf.provider.security_token = os.environ.get('AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN')
test.poll()
```

but seems pretty hacky and annoying because I have to do this every time I make a new layer2 object. Anyone else noticed this? Is this behavior intended for some reason, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Manual management of temporary security credentials is not only "pretty hacky", but also less secure. A better alternative would be to assign an IAM role to the instances, so they will automatically have all permissions of that Role without requiring explicit credentials.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html